# Category blog - hide category (options) makes tags disappear

Tags: tags, category-blog

I have had a category blog with a lot ot items and all of them has tags. I want to show tags, but when I choose Show Category [Hide] the tags is not visible. Show Category [Show] makes the tags visible. Why is this connected and how do I get around it?
Joomla 3.7.4

I tried with Protostar, same results as my default template.

Answer (score 2):

Using Protostar as Template and set in Menu "Show Category" to "Hide" and "Show Tags" to "Show" give what expected: No Category shown, Tags shown. No Matter if "Position of Article Info" is set to "Above, Below or Split".

So i prefer to Test Behaviour using Protostar to look if your Issue depends on Template/Override.

Comment: I tried with Protostar, same results as my default template.

Comment: Can i have a Look at your Site? If yes, please send per https://franzwohlkoenig.joomla.com/e-mail Login-Settings. I understand if you wouldn't cause you don't know me but it would be a little bit easier.

Comment: Don't share Admin credentials with anyone you wouldn't give your house keys to Jessica!